# Regexp Replace in Oracle not working as expected

Tags: oracle, regexp-replace

1. I want to eliminate `Bus\.` from below string and want to replace with Business. I am trying

   ```
   SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('CSP-Junior Associate (Bus\. Analyst equivalent)','Bus\.','Business')
   FROM DUAL
   ```

   but it is not working.
2. I want to eliminate `\` from below string and want to replace with null space. I am trying

   ```
   SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('CSP-Junior Associate (Bus\. Analyst equivalent)','\','')
   FROM DUAL
   ```

   but it is not working.

Comment: Your first query [definitely works](http://rextester.com/AOJZ36965).  I don't know what you are trying to do in the second query, but I would wager that you just have a small typo there.

Answer (score 0):

The first one worked for me, the second one is missing a backslash in your example, but I suspect you just need to escape it in the second argument to REGEXP_REPLACE() `'\\'`:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('CSP-Junior Associate\(Bus. Analyst equivalent)','\\','') FROM DUAL
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first one, you need to escape with \\, so try as

```
 SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE ('CSP-Junior Associate (Bus\. Analyst equivalent)',
                           'Bus\\.',
                           'Business')
      FROM DUAL
```

Output

```
CSP-Junior Associate (Business Analyst equivalent)
```

So the case with the second one

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE ('CSP-Junior Associate (Bus\. Analyst equivalent)',
                       '\\',
                       '')
  FROM DUAL
```